# Performance issue in a page retrieving many document sets using SPSiteDataQuery

Tags: 2013, web-part, performance, spsitedataquery

I am using SPSiteDataQuery in a Visual Web Part to get all document Sets inside all document libraries within a site collection. The client doesn't want to use Search. They have not configured Search at all. I have used contenttypeId to get all document sets like following

```
"<Where>" +
  "<BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId' /><Value Type='ContentTypeId'>0x0120D520003E969CCFD8D14029B93EB56937B41A66</Value></BeginsWith>" +
"</Where>";
```

It is ok, when it returns something about 500 document sets. But now the number of document sets has increased and it returns about 3000 document sets. So it makes the page to be very slow. Have you any suggestion to solve this performance issue?

Comment: Why not try paging? Fix a page size for the display and bring only that much data a time

Comment: Yes, it is one option, the problem is sometimes, they want to see all documentsets in a one single page

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I have a similar problem. Also, how are you displaying the results? In a DataTable? If so, how are you styling the DataTable? Thanks.

Comment: Not yet, but there is one alternative; having one list which contains all necessary fields which are needed to filter and show and create a new item on this list every time you create an item in all other lists which you want to search through.